# hector package problems

Tags: ros, package, hector

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have ros hydro full and I installed the hector_slam package with the command

sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-slam

I then tried to follow the tutorial but I had several problems.

when I try the command "rosmake hector_slam" I get multiple errors like this:

"[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "hector_geotiff" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue..."

I think it does not work because in the end it says:

"[ rosmake ] Built 0 packages with 0 failures."

I continued the tutorial after this because I have no ideia on what to do, and I did the command

"roslaunch hector_slam_launch tutorial.launch"

It gives me the following error:

"while processing /opt/ros/hydro/share/hector_geotiff/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch:
Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/hydro/share/hector_geotiff/launch/geotiff_mapper.launch'"

I really lost now. I can't even start the tutorial.

thx so much for the help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/89196/hector-package-problems/) by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2013-10-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know if its against the rules responding to my own question, but I solved the problem.

The sudo apt-get command doesn't update the hector_slam library.

It's not the most recent one. I found that there are missing files in the hector_geotiff paste.

---

Originally posted by [End-Effector](https://answers.ros.org/users/7606/end-effector/) with karma: 162 on 2013-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-09**:
It's great to answer your own question.  This will help anyone who has the same problem, and others won't spend time trying to answer it again.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-10-09**:
Where did you find the missing files? It sounds like there's a bug in the hector_slam packaging.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The launch files of packages hector_geotiff and hector_imu_attitude_to_tf were missing in version 0.3.0 of hector_slam in ROS hydro. I released version 0.3.1 which fixes the launch files issue and some other minor bugs yesterday. The new version should be available in the public repositories within the next days.

You do not have to invoke rosmake at all if you install the binary packages using
`sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-slam`. If you do, it is normal that no packages will be built as they already are.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2013-10-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1